# Trying to print the calendar i n python

Tags: python

I am trying to print the calendar for the given year , and tried the below code. Here the days and starting day of the week is not getting correctly. Here I am declaring a class Calender and calling the print month using the class variable. I am unable to print the output correctly and the align of the pattern is not correctly.

Tried Code:

```
**from datetime import date
class Calender():
   month_name=["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
   Year =2013
   month_days= [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
   day = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
   def day_week(self,Year,month):
     d = 1
     # month_days= [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
     #day = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
     #print(Calender.month_name[2])
     if (Year % 4 == 0 and (Year % 100 != 0 or Year % 400 == 0)) :
       self.month_days[1] = 29
     else:
       self.month_days[1]= 28
     if (Year < 1900 or month < 0 or month > 12 or d < 1 or d > self.month_days[month - 1]):
       print("This is an invalid date.\n")
       exit(1)
     
     for i in range(1990,Year):
       if (i % 4 == 0 and (i % 100 != 0 or i % 400 == 0)):
         d = d + 366
         #print(d)
       else:
         d = d + 365
         #print(d)
     M = d
     print(M)
     for i in range(1,month+1):
        D = self.month_days[i-1]
        M = M + D
     r = M % 7
     return self.day[r] 
    
   def print_month(self,Year,month):
     d =1
     print("\n\t",Calender.month_name[month],"-",Year)
     #print("\033[0;40m\n")
     x = Calender.day_week(self,Year,month+1)
     days = Calender().month_days[month]
     today = str(date.today())
     da_te = today[8:]
     mon = today[6:7]
     print(mon,month+1,da_te,x)
     print("\nSun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat")
     for i in range(1,x+1):
       print(i*" ",end=" ")
     for i in range(1,days+1):
        if (i == da_te):
          if (month+1 == mon ):
            print(" \033[1;33m",i)
            
            continue
        if((i+d+x-1)% 7 == 0):
          print(i,end="\n")
        else:
          print(i,end=" ")
        
        
      
      
    

if __name__ =="__main__":
  Year = int(input("Enter the Year: "))
  c = Calender()
  for j in range(0,12):
    c.print_month(Year,j)
  print("\n")**
```

And here is the output that i am getting,

Output:

```
~/Python-3$ python sample.py
Enter the Year: 2021

     March - 2021
11324
3 3 22 4

Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat
                1   2   3
  4   5   6   7   8   9   10
  11   12   13   14   15   16   17
  18   19   20   21   22   23   24
  25   26   27   28   29   30   31
```

Comment: Your supplied code contains multiple syntax errors.  Please fix that, and then test it by copying and pasting the code from your question into a new code file in your IDE, just like one of us would do to help you.  If the code won't run without modifications or additions, then it isn't fixed yet.  You shouldn't expect someone to help you with your code if your code isn't even correct Python code.

Comment: Why not using Python's built-in calendar ? `calendar.month(2021, 3, 4)` The last argument specifies the column width.

Comment: Thanks , but i am in learning the python as beginner I want to know the functionality of the each statement, so that i didn't use any built in functions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are missing an " in this line: `print("\n\tCalender.month_name[month],"-",Year)`

This should be `print(f"{self.month_name[month]} - {Year}")`

with line 3 changed to

```
self.month_name = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
]
```

where the `self.` is necessary and the rest is just making the code more readable.

Comment: Thanks I  added " in print statement, even though it is printing the same